# Use a for loop to iterate over a new Class in java

Tags: java, class, for-loop, iterator, implements

I am trying to get the hang of using the for loop with a new class
I created a simple java program that'll print from one number all the way to 
the other. I can't seem to get the hang of the for loop
Here is the sample code I have made to test it:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
public class Try {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      for (int i : new IntegerLoop(1, 9)) {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
      }

      System.out.println();

      for (int i : new IntegerLoop(-3, 3)) {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
      }

      System.out.println();

   }
}
```

This is the IntergerLoop class that just handles the first and last number to print out
import java.util.Iterator;

```
public class IntegerLoop implements Iterable<Integer>, Iterator<Integer> {
    int first, last;
    int nextInt;

    public IntegerLoop(int f, int l) {
        first = f;
        last = l;
        nextInt = first;
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return nextInt >= first && nextInt <= last;
    }

    public Integer next() {
        if (hasNext()) {
            int result = nextInt; // needs Iterator
            nextInt++;
            return result;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Iterables really shouldnt also be Iterators; their iterator() method should really return a new Iterator each time.

Comment: What does `new Class()` have to do with your code (not that it would work)?

Comment: I can't get it to properly print out the first to the last number. It doesn't really show me where the error is coming from but I am unsure if I am using the for loop in the right manner

Comment: Your iterator() method returning null is almost certainly an error.  I suspect you get a NullPointerException?

Comment: Yeah, it threw an error out for not having the return outside of the if loop as well

Answer (score 2):

You're getting a `NullPointerException` because you are returning `null` from the `iterator` method...

```
@Override
public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

The `iterator` method should return a new instance of an `iterator` each time it is called.

You could use a inner class of `Iterator`, but for this example, I separated it, as this makes the `IntegerIterator` more easily re-usable (IMHO)...

`IntegerLoop` class...

```
public class IntegerLoop implements Iterable<Integer> {

    int first, last;

    public IntegerLoop(int f, int l) {
        first = f;
        last = l;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
        return new IntegerIterator(first, last);
    }
}
```

`IntegerIterator` class...

```
public class IntegerIterator implements Iterator<Integer> {

    int first, last;
    int nextInt;

    public IntegerIterator(int first, int last) {
        this.first = first;
        this.last = last;
        this.nextInt = first;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return nextInt >= first && nextInt <= last;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer next() {
        if (hasNext()) {
            int result = nextInt; // needs Iterator
            nextInt++;
            return result;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: Awesome! thank you for the help! Was there any way to get IntegerLoop to work by implementing both Iterator and Iterable or does java just not allow this by design?

Comment: @Alex It wouldn't really make sense as the `iterator` method would really need to create a new instance of the `Iterator` each time it was called, you'd end up basically acting as a proxy, but that would just become a nightmarish mess